# Open a browser from the command line directly to a search result in google (or any other url based search engine)

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, alias

I want to be able to easily search something on google straight from the command line, but am having difficulties coming up with an alias.  Am I trying to make it look like this when used:

```
google "what I want to search for"
```

Currently I have got these aliases:

```
alias web='chromium-browser --new-window'
alias google='web https://www.google.com/search?q='
```

so the underlying command when using 'google "testing"' *should* look like this:

```
chromium-browser --new-window https://www.google.com/search?q="testing"
```

The problem is that it actually looks like this:

```
chromium-browser --new-window https://www.google.com/search?q= "testing"
```

Which means it will open two tabs, one with the unfinished search url and another with the url 'testing'.  I have tried adding an escape character so that the space would be 'escaped' out of the url, but to no avail.

Is there anyway I can do this using aliases?  If not, what else should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the solution that @ventsyv posted wasn't working for me, it gave me something to go off of at least.  Seems the $1 he used was for functions, not aliases, so I did some research in to that and created the function instead:

```
google() {
    chromium-browser --new-window https://www.google.com/search?q="$1" &
}
```

I put this inside a .bash_functions file I made in the same directly as .bashrc, then had .bashrc load this file during its run (you probably dont have to do this, but I found it helped separate aliases, functions, and the rest of the bashrc code).

I couldn't find an answer that made my original method of using aliases work, but if someone can help me with my original problem I will accept their answer =)

Answer (score 0):

No need for space after ?q= If you need spaces in the search terms, put them inside the quotes.

For example:

- https://www.google.com/#q=testing
- https://www.google.com/#q=testing code

  ## !/bin/bash

  chromium-browser --new-window https://www.google.com/search?q="$@"

Comment: I don't understand.  I haven't put any extra spaces in? Just the one that's needed between the alias name and the actually query text?

Comment: I see. Try writing a bash script. Something along the lines the example above should do it.